# Conditional operator in member-initialization list

Tags: c++

Suppose I have this class:

```
class foo
{
public:
    foo() { }
    foo(const std::string& s) : _s(s) { }

private:
    std::string _s;
};
```

Which is a member of another class:

```
class bar
{
public:
    bar(bool condition) : 
       _f(condition ? "go to string constructor" : **go to empty ctor**) 
    { 
    }

private:
    foo _f;
};
```

When initializing `_f` in `bar`'s member initialization list I would like to choose which constructor of `foo` to invoke based on `condition`.

What can I put instead of `go to empty ctor` to make this work? I thought of putting `foo()`, is there another way?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The result of a conditional operator is always a fixed type determined at compile time by finding a common type that both options can be converted to. (The exact rules are a little involved, but in common use it usually 'does the right thing'.)

In your example the simplest thing to do is to let that type be a temporary `foo` and then use the copy constructor to intialize `_f` in bar.

You can do this as follows.

```
_f( condition ? foo("string") : foo() )
```

Comment: With C++11, I'd recommend a move-constructor over a copy-constructor, but the technique is good.

Comment: @Richard: I wasn't recommending an explicit use of the copy constructor (not that that's possible to my knowledge). The example I showed will use a move constructor when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If passing an empty string is the equivalent of calling to no-arg constructor you could do the following:

```
_f(condition ? "string" : "")
```

This would save you the copy.